# How to merge back the processes by sample after splitting by chromosome in Nextflow?

Tags: nextflow

I have a pipeline that has an input list of samples. I would like to split those samples by chromosomes, process each chromosome apart, and then merge them back by sample name.

Here's an example:

```java
samplesList = Channel.from(["sample1", "sample2"])

// A process that splits the samples by chromosome as an example
// In my actual case, I have a VCF that is split by `snpSift Split` command
// and generates files like [sample]_[chr].vcf
// In the example below, I only gave sample1
// But take into consideration that I have multiple samples

process bar {
   echo true

  output:
    file("*.tsv") into bar_output

  script:
  """
  echo 1 > sample1_chr1.tsv
  echo 2 > sample1_chr2.tsv
  echo 3 > sample1_chr3.tsv
  echo 4 > sample1_chr4.tsv
  echo 5 > sample1_chr5.tsv
  """
}

// Process each chromosome apart for each sample
// This means the output of the process foo
// is only ONE chromosome per sample
process foo {
  input:
    each x from bar_output  // to treat each file separately from the channel
  output:
    file("*.tsv") into xasxa
  script:
    """
    echo \\\$(cat $x)\\\$(cat $x) > sample1_chr\\\$(cat $x)_2.tsv
    """
}

// How should I write the next process to group back them together by sample name?
// I do not wish to do a collect() on channel foo because it will force 
// all the processes of foo to finish first.
// In this example, foo would emit 5 different channels of chromosome for sample1
// This process should merge sample1 only when all chromosomes are processed
// independently of other samples. 
process mergeChromosomesBySamples {
   input:
     ???
}
```

As the example above, the process `mergeChromosomesBySamples` should return something similar/close to

```java
["sample1", ["/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr1.tsv",
             "/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr2.tsv",
             "/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr3.tsv",
             "/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr4.tsv",
             "/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr5.tsv"]
]
```

---

EDIT1: more explication for the process `mergeChromosomesBySamples` is given in the comments and as follows ...

The channel `xasxa` processes each chromosome apart, this means that the output of the channel `xasxa` contains only one chromosome of the sample like `"/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr1.tsv"` only. My goal is then to merge the processes out `xasxa` for each sample together.

I do not wish to use `collect()` in this case because it would have to force all the processes of foo to finish before. I want them to work independently for each sample.

Where each sample has its own VCF generated and I process them independently.

EDIT2: Here's a graph of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

If I use `.collect()`, then all the processing on the chromosomes of all the samples has to finish first before being able to merge them, which is something I do not want.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution that answers my problem finally.

So, here are two different methods below, one which does exactly what I want while the other has to wait for all the previous processes to finish:

**First method**: waiting for previous process to finish using `.groupTuple()` like what @Pallie mentionned. This method is simpler than the second method. The problem is that it has to wait for the previous processes to finish. I want my samples to be treated in parallel. If I missed something with the logic of the method, please feel free to edit.

```java
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

// my samples
samplesList = Channel.from(["sample1", "sample2"])

// the process that is supposed to split the sample by chromosomes
process foo {
      echo true
      cpus 1
      memory '1 MB'
      executor 'local'

      input:
         val(x) from samplesList
      output:
         file("*.vcf") into foo_out
         val(x) into output_sample
      script:
      """
         echo 1 > ${x}_chr1.vcf
         echo 2 > ${x}_chr2.vcf
      """
}

//Combine the samples by chromosome and filter out only the samples that match the files output
foo_out.flatten().combine(output_sample).filter{ it[0].toString().contains(it[1].toString()) }.set{maybework}

// the process that is supposed to treat each chromosome apart
process bar {
      echo true
      cpus 1
      memory '1 MB'
      executor 'local'

      input:
         set file(y), val(x) from maybework
      output:
         set val(x), file("*chr*vcf") into bar_out
      script:
      """
         echo ${x}
         filename=\\\$(basename -- ${y})
         chromosome=\\\$(echo "\\\${filename%.*}" | cut -f2 -d'_')
         cat ${y} > ${x}_"\\\$chromosome"_"\\\$chromosome".vcf
         if [ ${x} == "sample2" ]; then sleep 20; fi
      """
}

// the process that merges back the chromosomes by sample
process mergefoobar {
      echo true
      cpus 1
      memory '1 MB'
      executor 'local'

      input:
      set val(sample), file(x) from bar_out.groupTuple()

      script:
      """
         echo $sample
         echo ${x}
      """
}
```

will output:
[image: FirstMethod]
As you can see above, the process `mergefoobar` is still waiting for all the processes of `bar` to finish.

**Second method**: does not wait for the previous processes to finish, uses `.join()` for each chromosome... Yes, the downside is that you would have to write the `join()` for all the chromosomes. Additionally, if you use `snpSift Split`, one sample may generate 3 files out of 5 (because only 3 chromosomes had variants listed in them), you would need to create the other empty VCF files because the output excepts them.

```java
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

// my samples
samplesList = Channel.from(["sample1", "sample2"])

// the process that is supposed to split the sample by chromosomes
process foo {
      echo true
      cpus 1
      memory '1 MB'
      executor 'local'

      input:
         val(x) from samplesList
      output:
         file("*.vcf") into foo_out
         val(x) into output_sample
      script:
      """
         echo 1 > ${x}_chr1.vcf
     echo 2 > ${x}_chr2.vcf
         echo X > ${x}_chrX.vcf
     echo Y > ${x}_chrY.vcf
      """
}

//Combine the samples by chromosome and filter out only the samples that match the files output
foo_out.flatten().combine(output_sample).filter{ it[0].toString().contains(it[1].toString()) }.set{maybework}

// the process that is supposed to treat each chromosome apart
process bar {
      echo true
      cpus 1
      memory '1 MB'
      executor 'local'

      input:
         set file(y), val(x) from maybework
      output:
         set val(x), file("*chr1*vcf") optional true into bar_out1
         set val(x), file("*chr2*vcf") optional true into bar_out2
         set val(x), file("*chrX*vcf") optional true into bar_outX
         set val(x), file("*chrY*vcf") optional true into bar_outY
      script:
      """
         echo ${x}
     filename=\\\$(basename -- ${y})
         chromosome=\\\$(echo "\\\${filename%.*}" | cut -f2 -d'_')
         cat ${y} > ${x}_"\\\$chromosome"_"\\\$chromosome".vcf
         if [ ${x} == "sample2" ]; then sleep 20; fi
      """
}

// the process that merges back the chromosomes by sample
process mergefoobar {
      echo true
      cpus 1
      memory '1 MB'
      executor 'local'

      input:
      set val(sample), file(x), file(y), file(i), file(t) from bar_out1.join(bar_out2).join(bar_outX).join(bar_outY)

      script:
      """
         echo $sample
     echo ${x}
         echo ${y}
     echo ${i}
         echo ${t}
      """
}
```

[image: SecondMethod]
Above, you see that the process mergefoobar has launched even if the previous bar has not finished yet.

I hope this also helps anyone in the future who might have this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [groupBy operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#groupby). If the content of channel `xasxa` is:

`["/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr1.tsv", "/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr2.tsv", "/path/to/workdir/sample2_chr1.tsv", "/path/to/workdir/sample2_chr2.tsv`

You could probably do:

`xasxa.groupBy{ it -> it.fileName.toString().split("_")[0] }`

The result would be a channel with:

`[sample1:[/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr1.tsv, /path/to/workdir/sample1_chr2.tsv, sample2:[/path/to/workdir/sample2_chr1.tsv, /path/to/workdir/sample2_chr1.tsv]]`

This breaks if you have an underscore in your samplename before `_chr*`. More robust would be to initialise all channels with a sample value, so that each channel is in the form of [samplename, chromosome]. Then all you need is a `groupTuple` on your channel.

Comment: The channel `xasxa` processes each chromosome apart, this means that the output of the channel `xasxa` contains only one chromosome of the sample like `"/path/to/workdir/sample1_chr1.tsv"` only. My goal is then to merge the processes out `xasxa` for each sample together. Sorry if that wasn't clear in my explanation.

Comment: Still not exactly sure what you need, does a `.collect()` on  `xasxa` do what you wish?

Comment: I do not wish to use `collect()` in this case because it would have to force all the processes of `foo` to finish before. I want them to work independently for each sample.

Comment: Do you start with a single vcf that contains multiple samples?

Comment: No, each sample has his own VCF generated and I process them independantly. BTW, thanks for the proposed solution.